# Why is BLE beacon technology used instead of Wi-Fi infrastructure which is already installed?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, wifi, ibeacon, beacon

The Beacon radiates signal. A nearby Bluetooth enabled device receives this signal. When a particular application recognizes its signal, it connects it to an action or content track stored in the cloud and allows the user to view it. By editing the application on your phone, you can set how it reacts to signals.

For example:

Beacon systems are installed in the shops within a mall. All Beacons have their own fixed ones. When the signal of Beacon, which broadcasts with its own private ID, reaches your phone, the application of the shopping center (which should be pre-installed) will process this signal and give you outputs such as the store discount coupon, navigation proposal varying according to the application's program.

When I set out from this example, I have the following question in my mind. **Why is BLE beacon technology used instead of Wi-Fi infrastructure (already installed in phone and mall)?** **When we periodically scan Wi-Fi signals, we can access SSID, MAC and RSSI information. When we use this information as a query tool by using an application, the approximation recognition with the beacon is completed.** In this way, we do not have to invest in BLE beacon infrastructure. What is the keypoint of BLE beacon technology? Why do people need to use this technology?

Comment: Wi-Fi base stations don't have a calibrated TxPower value available, so estimating the proximity isn't as accurate. Also they are placed with Wi-Fi reception in mind and not necessarily placed in places that are useful for e.g. indoor navigation or triggering actions at specific locations. They are also more expensive, so their number is minimized. Beacons can be placed to specific locations that support their use for specific purposes, they are cheaper, so more of them can be installed. They are also easier to replace without side effects as you can use the same old ID with a new beacon.

Comment: On the other hand, now (soon) we have [Wi-Fi RTT](https://www.punosmobile.com/en/blog/building-location-aware-services-with-android-9-wi-fi-rtt/).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest answer is in the fact that BLE devices are extremely power conscious (therefore the name, Bluetooth **Low Energy**). A BLE beacon can run on a coin cell battery for a year or even more without any issue. This is a huge advantage over WiFi which is relatively considered power hungry. It is also an advantage over other low energy wireless technologies (e.g. ZigBee, ANT, etc) in that phones and tablets have Bluetooth built in and therefore do not require any extra hardware. There may be other minor reasons such as indoor performance and interference, but the Low Energy aspect is the main differentiator.

There are many articles that discuss this in length, I recommend the following:-

- [Comparing Low Power Wireless Technologies](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/articles/techzone/2017/oct/comparing-low-power-wireless-technologies)
- [BLE vs WiFi: Which is Better for IoT Product Development](https://www.cabotsolutions.com/2018/02/ble-vs-wi-fi-which-is-better-for-iot-product-development)
- [The Pros and Cons of Bluetooth Low Energy](https://www.electronicsweekly.com/news/design/communications/pros-cons-bluetooth-low-energy-2014-10/)

Finally, I recommend posting a similar question in the future to other StackExchange networks (e.g. [ElectricalEngineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/30489/youssif-saeed)) as StackOverflow is mainly for programming related questions and you'd probably get more traction and better answers in other sites.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer.  Another major reason to use BLE over WiFi for  Android and iOS apps is that these mobile operating systems are much more permissive in letting apps scan for BLE advertisements than WiFi.  iOS blocks apps from doing programmatic  WiFi scans at all and blocks reading nearby SSIDs other than the one the phone is connected to.  Android different restrictions.  Both operating systems allow apps to use BLE but not WiFi for location determination.

Comment: Based on your answer, I conclude that the use of BLE should only be preferred in the first installation when considered in terms of low power consumption.

Comment: The same application can be done if a Wi-Fi infrastructure application is allowed to scan the SSID.  It seems there is no superiority like the ZigBee network allows more nodes/devices than Wi-Fi.

Comment: The superiority is in the power consumption of BLE. In the second link I added, it is stated "Wi-Fi requires 10 times more power than BLE, even if they are performing the same tasks". This is why BLE is very popular for battery powered embedded devices, such as beacons. Moreover, as davidgyoung added, the mobile operating systems are a lot more permissive and expose API to allow you to use BLE for location determination, which I now see equally as important as the power consumption